# How to indicate to Ventoy (Bootable USB) to ignore some content in the pen drive?

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, bootable-media

For some laptops where do not exist the CD-ROM, for boot purposes can be used [Ventoy
A New Bootable USB Solution](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) - sadly so far is mandatory apply just only once time a **formatting** process to the pen drive, it to install this software.

Because this pen drive is going to have few `.iso` files, such as for `GParted`, `Ubuntu` and `Fedora` software - has no sense waste the rest of the capacity of the pen drive itself - for example if the pen drive has a capacity of 16G (there is no available pen drives with 8GB and smaller anymore) and the `.iso` images makes a total for example of 7GB - as you can see 9GB are free yet.

What can be do to create a special directory where Ventoy can ignore and do not touch the data?

Therefore if is added or removed `.iso` files the other data should be remain in peace.

Comment: You can create a directory or more than one, doesn't need to be "special" and Ventoy by itself touches nothing on the drive, not even the ISOs. Ventoy's only purpose is to be a 1st stage bootloader that chainloads whatever bootable image (ISO) it find at the root and ignores anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can reserve some space at the bottom of the disk at install time of ventoy using `-r` option:

```
Ventoy2Disk.sh CMD [ OPTION ] /dev/sdX
[...]
   -r SIZE_MB  preserve some space at the bottom of the disk (only for install)
[...]
```

[Documentation here.](https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_start.html#doc_linux_cli)

e.g.:

```
$ sudo ./Ventoy2Disk.sh -i /dev/sda -r 65536

**********************************************
      Ventoy: 1.0.88  x86_64
      longpanda admin@ventoy.net
      https://www.ventoy.net
**********************************************

Disk : /dev/sda
Model: Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 (scsi)
Size : 115 GB
Style: MBR

You will reserve 65536 MB disk space

Attention:
You will install Ventoy to /dev/sda.
All the data on the disk /dev/sda will be lost!!!

Continue? (y/n) y

[...]
```